# Hook turn limitations

Tags: melbourne

How many vehicles could stand by for a hook turn in Melbourne, Victoria, Australia? I can't find its answer anywhere. And if there's a restriction, what do the vehicles who need to turn, do? Let's assume that you're only allowed to perform a right hook turn from far left only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the [Official VicRoads Hook turn Info](https://www.vicroads.vic.gov.au/safety-and-road-rules/road-rules/a-to-z-of-road-rules/turning). It doesn't directly answer the question of how many can wait for a hook turn.

The answer has to be "as many as will fit into the intersection".

Any car not already in the intersection would have to go through a red light to complete the hook turn. So I guess technically the answer above should be "no more than can fit into the intersection"...

Comment: So this would mean that if the road joining from the left side has 2 lanes joining the intersection, there'd be a room for 2 vehicles? (1 behind the other)

Comment: @AkashAgarwal the video linked shows 2 cars, but even in that example there would be space for a 3rd card behind them. From observation I can say I've seen the entire left lane of traffic back to the light full of cars making hook turns. And yes. always 1 behind the other.

Comment: And I suppose, the cars that don't fit into the intersection remain in the far left lane of the road until they find a space in the intersection for themselves?

Comment: Yes. Cars that don't fit wait in the left lane (which is blocked by the hook turners anyway). The light change and so now the waiting car is facing a red light and can't go anyway. Then the lights change again and the car(s) that didn't fit can now enter the intersection and wait for their chance to do a hook turn.